# Canvas not reading svg viewport inside another svg on safari

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, viewport

My issue is a little complicated.

I am rendering a canvas inside an *<svg>* which is inside another *<svg>*. *<anvas>* is reading on the viewport of outermost *<svg>* while completely ignoring the inner one.

Here is a jsfiddle with the complete code:
https://jsfiddle.net/doLfz1a0/1/

Here is a simplification of the issue:

```js
canvas = $('#fontstyle_straight_2_canvas')[0]
font = '20px arial'

ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
w = canvas.width
ctx.font = font
ctx.textBaseline = 'top'
ctx.textAlign = 'center'
ctx.lineWidth = 2
ctx.fillStyle = 'black'

text = 'blackdown'

ctx.fillText(text, w * 0.5, 0, w)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="288px" height="308.8804px" viewBox="0 0 288 308.8804">
  <g>
    <g>
      <svg x="77.3999px" height="57.1001px" y="59px" width="133.6001px" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" viewBox="0 0 160 160" style="display: inline;">
        <g>
          <g fill="#000000">
            <rect x="8.4517" y="89.25" fill="red" width="146.5483" height="21.1494"></rect>
            <foreignObject id="fontstyle_straight_2_fo" x="8.4517" y="89.25" fill="none" width="146.5483" height="31">
              <canvas x="8.4517" y="89.25" width="146.5483" height="31" id="fontstyle_straight_2_canvas"></canvas>
            </foreignObject>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

On Chrome and Firefox, the text rendered by the canvas API fits in the red rectangle, while in Safari 12.0.2, the canvas is completely off.

Comment: When your issue is complicated, simplify it. See How to create an [MCVE]. Here I made one for you, but next time, please do it directly.

Comment: Why do you need a canvas to write the text? It can be done with SVG. Should you need a image instead of the text, it can be done with SVG, as you find out in your last question.

Comment: @enxaneta finding why there is a discrepancy between implementations is a very valid question, moreover with the emergence of SVG2 which does change a lot of things in this area. And there are good cases one would want a canvas or other HTML foreign element  to be correctly placed inside an svg.

Comment: If you've found a webkit bug [report it here](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)